# Call to undefined function objectsIntoArray() -PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse xml into array using `objectsIntoArray()` using PHP and i am getting error `Call to undefined function objectsIntoArray()`.

please anybody help

Comment: You haven't defined `objectsIntoArray()`. I believe what you want is in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#97555).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>SimpleXML Extension is missing, not installed, or you have a wrong PHP version or SimpleXML version.</s>

1. Check `phpinfo()` and check http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php
2. Post code

So `objectsIntoArray()` it's just a hand-made function. It isn't built into php so you have to include it manually.

```
<?php 

    function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array()){
        $arrData = array();
        if (is_object($arrObjData)) 
            $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);

        if (is_array($arrObjData)) 
            foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {
                if(is_object($value) || is_array($value)) 
                    $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices); 

                if(in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) 
                     continue;

                $arrData[$index] = $value;
            }

        return $arrData;
    }

    $xmlString = "
        <html>
            <head>
                <link blabla='whargarbl' />
            </head>
        </html>
    "; 
    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString); 
    $arrayXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObject);
    die(var_dump($arrayXml));
?>
```

Comment: Simplexml support is enabled in php.iniRevision - $Revision: 1.151.2.22.2.35.2.32 $ and PHP Version is 5.3.0.Please advise

Comment: $xmlString = file_get_contents($fileName);
 $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
 $arrayXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObject);

Comment: It's an object member. Use `$arrayXml =  $xmlObject->objectsIntoArray($xmlObject); `

Comment: now error changed to Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::objectsIntoArray()

Answer (score 1):

`objectsIntoArray()` isn't a standard built-in function in PHP, so if you haven't written it yourself then it will indeed be undefined.

If you have written it, then perhaps you haven't included the appropriate file that contains the function.

I notice that there someone has posted a function with the same name into the comments in the PHP manual page for the SimpleXML class -- see http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php and search for `objectsIntoArray`. If this is the function you were looking for, you could copy+paste it directly from here and use it.